# Should a key be directly on your component or on the container element within your component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I want to return one of my components from a map, can I just do this?

```
<Component data={data} key={`component-${data.id}`} />
```

or, are you supposed to do something like this, within the component itself?

```
const Component = ({data}) => {
  return (
     <div key={`component-${data.id}`}>
     // Rest of component
     </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify where you're using map

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are fine they work both its your own personal preference honestly I think if you do it like the first example you won't get warnings  I assume you're trying something like this hope this clears it up if not let me know

```
return (
    <>
      {Dataa.map((data) =>
        <Component data={data} key= 
        {`component-${data.id}`} />
      )}
    </>
  );
```

Refer docs for further clarification:
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: I would not say that it's only based on personal preference - since according to the documentation that you linked to: "For example, if you extract a ListItem component, you should keep the key on the <ListItem /> elements in the array rather than on the <li> element in the ListItem itself." So in this case it would be correct to place the key on the Component rather than the <div> within the Component.

Comment: The question doesn't clarify exactly how they're doing it but at most they'll get a warning code will run regardless but yes you're right